# PL/SQL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE

Tags: plsql

i have problem with  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE   i made  2  of them
must one show before salary updated and  one after salary  updated
but both of them show me the update
only mabye i make  something wrong  check the code please  .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SET_SALARY (P_EMP_ID NUMBER , P_ADD_SAL NUMBER)
 IS 
V_NAME VARCHAR2(50) ;
V_SALARY NUMBER ;
V_MANG_NAME VARCHAR2(50); 
V_MANG_SAL NUMBER ;
V_EMP_ID NUMBER ;
V_MNG_ID NUMBER ;
BEGIN 
SELECT LAST_NAME , SALARY  
INTO  V_NAME , V_SALARY 
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = P_EMP_ID ;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (V_NAME || ' Before: '||V_SALARY );  <===(must show for select)
UPDATE EMPLOYEES
SET SALARY = SALARY + P_ADD_SAL
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = P_EMP_ID ;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (V_NAME || ' After: '||V_SALARY ); <==(must show after update)
SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID , E.LAST_NAME, E.SALARY ,E.MANAGER_ID,M.LAST_NAME , M.SALARY  
INTO V_EMP_ID, V_NAME , V_SALARY ,V_MNG_ID,V_MANG_NAME , V_MANG_SAL 
FROM EMPLOYEES E , EMPLOYEES M 
WHERE E.MANAGER_ID = M.EMPLOYEE_ID 
AND E.EMPLOYEE_ID = P_EMP_ID ;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (V_MANG_NAME || ' Before: '||V_MANG_SAL );<===(must show for select)
UPDATE EMPLOYEES 
SET SALARY = SALARY  + ( P_ADD_SAL / 2 ) 
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = V_MNG_ID ;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (V_MANG_NAME || ' AFTER: '||V_MANG_SAL );<==(must show after update)
END ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are never updating the variable values of `V_SALARY` and `V_MANG_SAL` after the initial `SELECT INTO` statements.

If you want to do that you need to add a `RETURNING` clause to your update statements.  Take the first one as an example:

```sql
UPDATE EMPLOYEES
SET SALARY = SALARY + P_ADD_SAL
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = P_EMP_ID 
RETURNING salary INTO v_salary;
```

That will update the value in the variable `V_SALARY` with the updated value.